# Python3.8: combine two datetime variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following code

```
import datetime
Date_0 = [datetime.date(2021,3,10), datetime.date(2021,3,11)]
Date_1 = datetime.date(2021,3,12)
Date_combine = [Date_0, Date_1]
```

I got the result of Data_combine: [[2021-03-10, 2021-03-11], 2021-03-12]
But I want to get this: [2021-03-10, 2021-03-11, 2021-03-12]

How could I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: `Date_0.append(Date_1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a new `list` that unpacks the existing `list` and adds on the new element:

```
Date_combine = [*Date_0, Date_1]
```

The `*` says "unpack the contents of `Date_0` here without the wrapping" (see [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for details). Put `*`s before any element that is itself a `list` or other iterable and you want to include the *contents* of, leave it off for the values you want to include as themselves, without unpacking.

On older Python (pre-3.5), you could use concatenation for a simple case like this, by wrapping the non-`list` elements in temporary `list`s e.g.:

```
Date_combine = Date_0 + [Date_1]
```

or if you don't need it to be a *new* `list`, and modifying `Date_0` in place is fine, the even simpler:

```
Date_0.append(Date_1)
```